# Nokogiri gemspec invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 in jruby on windows platform

Tags: windows, jruby, nokogiri

I encountered a new error, which I got in my application.

> invalid byte sequence in UTF-8

Comment: i had provided solution on this

Comment: You can ask and answer your own question if you want. (It's great when you find and solve something yourself). You should still post your answer as an answer, not as part of the question. Can you clarify the question a bit though too perhaps? It's a little hard to understand.

Comment: It sounds like you're saying that you could not install Nokogiri on Windows using jRuby? Was that from the network, or did you fetch the Nokogiri GitHub repo and try to build the gem locally?

Comment: @Flexo: thanks for suggestion i will definitely post my answer as an answer

Answer (score 1):

the solution:

"Nokogiri (\xE9?\xB8)" just replace this with the following solution: "Nokogiri (\xE9\x8B\xB8)

Answer (score 1):

Installing the Nokogiri gem gives the following error:

```
$ jruby -S gem install nokogiri
Fetching: nokogiri-1.5.5-java.gem (100%)
Invalid gemspec in [c:/jruby-1.7.0.preview1/lib/ruby/gems/shared/specifications/nokogiri-1.5.5-java.
gemspec]: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
Successfully installed nokogiri-1.5.5-java
1 gem installed
```

To remove the error message do the following as per "Flexo's post".

```
C:\jruby-1.7.0.preview1\lib\ruby\gems\shared\specifications\nokogiri-1.5.5-java.gemspec and replace all references of "Nokogiri (\xE9?\xB8)" with "Nokogiri (\xE9\x8B\xB8)".
```